# How to block a python-socketio client until a server event response is received?

Tags: python, python-socketio

I'm trying to write a python script that connects to a nodejs server using socket.io package. The server receives the events from the client and responds with other events. As an example, let's say that the client sends an "getHome" events and the server responds with a "homePage" event with some data. What I want is so be able to send an event with the client and block the execution of the script until the response is received, process the response and then do something else based on the server response. The code I wrote is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()

@sio.event
def message(data):
    print(data)

@sio.event
def homePage(data):
    print(data)

sio.connect('http://docedit/socket.io/')

print("First call")
sio.emit("getHome")
print("Second call")
sio.emit("getHome")
```

The problem is that the second call to "emit" is done before receiving the response for the first one. The output of the script is something like:

```
First call
Second call
Welcome to Home  <- response from the server
Welcome to Home  <- response from the server
```

Reading the documentation, I tried to use "call" instead of "emit" but then the execution blocks forever, even if the homePage function executes normally:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()

@sio.event
def message(data):
    print(data)

@sio.event
def homePage(data):
    print(data)

sio.connect('http://docedit/socket.io/')

print("First call")
sio.call("getHome")
print("Second call")
sio.call("getHome")
```

Output:

```
First call
Welcome to Home <- response from the server
```

I didn't find an example with call so maybe I'm using it wrong...any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to use some kind of lock

```
from threading import Lock
lock_me = Lock()

lock_me.acquire() #ensure lock is acquire beforehand

import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()

@sio.event
def message(data):
    print(data)

@sio.event
def homePage(data):
    print(data)
    lock_me.release()

sio.connect('http://docedit/socket.io/')

print("First call")
sio.emit("getHome")
lock_me.acquire()
print("Second call")
sio.emit("getHome")
```

Another way is with conditions or notify :)

Comment: Yeah I guess that will do. Thanks a lot!